# AWS Lambda: Accuracy of system clock

Tags: aws-lambda

What is the guaranteed maximum system clock error observed in AWS Lambda functions?

More specifically, across Lambda instances in the same AWS Region (not AZ), what is the maximum difference of system clock times that could be observed?

I can't find anything in AWS documentation about this.

Comment: Best info I found so far: "Lambda is configured to use stratum 3 clocks"...

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=730829&#730829

Comment: excellent question! — stratum 3 is pretty darn good — good enough for              my work

Comment: @GeekStocks How accurate is darn good? Can I assume it's 100ms accurate? 
I have a weird race condition where one cortical thing shows up in the logs 100ms after the other. Can I trust the order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS Lambda clocks are synchronized using NTP, so the accuracy is as good as what NTP can provide

Quoting from what I found in the Lambda documentation here

*TZ – The environment's time zone (UTC). The execution environment uses NTP to synchronize the system clock*

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-dg.pdf

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer even though it doesn't directly answer my question. I guess the real answer is "there are no guarantees about maximum clock differences in Lambda and any synchronization design cannot rely on such maxima".

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but no one answered properly here, so I did some research and find out about the Amazon Time Sync Service

---

[The Amazon Time Sync Service](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/introducing-the-amazon-time-sync-service/) Synchronize the Lambda functions, it's built upon Amazon's proven network infrastructure. The service utilizes a fleet of redundant satellite-connected and atomic reference clocks in AWS regions to deliver current time readings of the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) global standard.

So yes, the calling (A) function's timestamp should be before the timestamp of the called (B) function. However, Lambda runs in a networked environment consisting of various components that could cause network errors. Although the timestamps are very accurate, there could be very few situations where higher latencies can occur.


Read More about it here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/keeping-time-with-amazon-time-sync-service/